# UnimplementedFeatureError: Copying of type struct FishData.temperature_location memory[10] memory to storage not yet supported

Tags: solidity

I am working on a fish supply chain contract in Solidity. Within the contract, I have defined two structs: fish_info and temperature_location. The fish_info struct contains an array of temperature_location structs, with a fixed length of 10. I'm trying to store a dynamic array of fish_info structs in a mapping, where each fish is recorded based on the date.

```
    pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
/**
 * fish supply chain
 */
contract FishData {
    //fish information
    struct fish_info {
        string species;
        string initialLocation;
        uint256 initialTimestamp;
        uint256 initialTemperature;
        temperature_location[10] history;
    }
    
    struct temperature_location {
        uint256 timestamp;
        uint256 temperature;
        string location;
        bool safety;
    }
    
 
    mapping (uint256 => fish_info[]) public fish_infoList;

    event RecordData(uint256 indexed date, string species, string initialLocation, uint256 initialTimestamp, temperature_location[10] history);

    /**
     * record Capture Data
     */
    function recordCaptureData (uint256 date, string memory species, string memory initialLocation, uint256 initialTimestamp, uint256 initialTemperature) public {
        temperature_location memory initialHistory;
        fish_info memory newinfo;
        initialHistory = temperature_location(block.timestamp, initialTemperature, initialLocation, true);
        newinfo.history[0] = initialHistory;
        newinfo = fish_info(species, initialLocation, block.timestamp, initialTemperature, newinfo.history);
        

        fish_infoList[date].push(newinfo);
        emit RecordData(date, newinfo.species, newinfo.initialLocation, newinfo.initialTimestamp, newinfo.history);
    }
}
```

The error specifically occurs when I try to assign initialHistory to newinfo.history[0]. It seems that Solidity does not yet support copying a dynamic array of structs to storage, even though pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2 is used.

I'm seeking guidance on how to overcome this issue and successfully store a dynamic array of structs in storage, within the constraints of Solidity's current capabilities. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is indeed impossible. What I suggest is to use another mapping to store the temperature_location[], while the fish_info will have another member - an id. This id would then be used to obtain the temperature_location[] from the mapping. I modified your code accordingly:

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
/**
 * fish supply chain
 */
contract FishData {
    //fish information
    struct fish_info {
        uint256 id;
        string species;
        string initialLocation;
        uint256 initialTimestamp;
        uint256 initialTemperature;
    }

    struct temperature_location {
        uint256 timestamp;
        uint256 temperature;
        string location;
        bool safety;
    }
    
    uint256 fishInfoId;
    mapping (uint256 => fish_info[]) public fish_infoList;
    mapping (uint256 => temperature_location[]) public locationList;

    event RecordData(uint256 indexed date, string species, string initialLocation, uint256 initialTimestamp, temperature_location[] history);

    /**
     * record Capture Data
     */
    function recordCaptureData (uint256 date, string memory species, string memory initialLocation, uint256 initialTimestamp, uint256 initialTemperature) public {
        temperature_location memory initialHistory;
        fish_info memory newinfo;
        initialHistory = temperature_location(block.timestamp, initialTemperature, initialLocation, true);
        
        newinfo = fish_info(fishInfoId, species, initialLocation, block.timestamp, initialTemperature);
        
        locationList[fishInfoId].push(initialHistory);

        fish_infoList[date].push(newinfo);

        fishInfoId++;
        emit RecordData(date, newinfo.species, newinfo.initialLocation, newinfo.initialTimestamp, locationList[fishInfoId]);
    }
}
```

with this approach your code can retain the structure of the function and the event, however there will be slightly more to keep in the storage.

Comment: thank you! using mapping and fishInfoId is a good way, I also solve this problem with code following:

Comment: Interesting, so you used the state variable array as a buffer instead of memory. That worked indeed, but has a huge gas cost in it due to multiple sstore, my functions costs 322467, while yours 908314. You might want to consider that too.

Answer (score 0):

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
/**
 * fish supply chain
 */
contract FishData {
    struct fish_info {
        string species;
        string initialLocation;
        uint256 initialTimestamp;
        uint256 initialTemperature;
        temperature_location[10] history;
    }
    struct temperature_location {
        uint256 timestamp;
        uint256 temperature;
        string location;
        bool safety;
    }
    mapping (uint256 => fish_info[]) public fish_infoList;
    event RecordData(uint256 indexed date, string species, string initialLocation, uint256 initialTimestamp, temperature_location[10] history);
    temperature_location[10] public historys;
    fish_info public newinfo;
function recordCaptureData (uint256 date, string memory species, string memory initialLocation, uint256 initialTimestamp, uint256 initialTemperature) public {
        
        historys[0].timestamp = block.timestamp;
        historys[0].temperature = initialTemperature;
        historys[0].location = initialLocation;
        historys[0].safety = true;

        newinfo.species = species;
        newinfo.initialLocation = initialLocation;
        newinfo.initialTimestamp = block.timestamp;
        newinfo.initialTemperature = initialTemperature;
        newinfo.history = historys;
        
        fish_infoList[date].push(newinfo);
        emit RecordData(date, newinfo.species, newinfo.initialLocation, newinfo.initialTimestamp, newinfo.history);
    }
}
```